# How can i get the values of second index from Debug area and show these values in "UILables"

Tags: json, swift, xcode

i want to show the highlighted values in UILables i got the values of first Index Using Alamofire but i don't know how to get values of second index

let outPut = dlc.value(forKey: "flightdetail_array") as! NSArray for item in outPut { let tempitem = item as! NSDictionary self.arrival_Date.text = (tempitem.value(forKey: "arrival_date") as! String)

[image]

Comment: Can you please give us some more information, if you don't mind?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: let data = result ["flightdetail_array"] as? NSArray
let secondIndex = data[1] as! NSDictionary
lblarrival_date.text = secondIndex.value(forKey: "arrival_date") as? String

Comment: i want to show the highlighted values in UILables i got the values of first Index Using Alamofire but i don't know how to get values of second index

Comment: @BenRockey Don't use NSArray and NSDictionary in swift

Comment: @MuhammadHassaan show your code. How you got the values of first index

Comment: @RajeshKumarR let outPut = dlc.value(forKey: "flightdetail_array") as! NSArray
                        
                        for item in outPut
                        {
                            let tempitem = item as! NSDictionary
                            self.arrival_Date.text = (tempitem.value(forKey: "arrival_date") as! String)

Comment: @MuhammadHassaan Please don't put additional information in the comments. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56180783/edit) the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if let output = dlc["flightdetail_array"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    if output.indices.contains(1) {
        let tempItem = output[1]//index of the element in array
        if let arrivalDate = tempitem["arrival_date"] as? String {
            self.arrivalDate.text = arrivalDate
        }
    }
}
```

Don't use NSArray and NSDictionary in swift. Use [Array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) and [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary)

Avoid force unwrapping

Don't use underscore in variable names. Use `arrivalDate` instead of `arrival_Date`